# Any browser allow multiple profiles under one email account and sync across devices?

Tags: browser, browser-addons

As a developer, I am working with multiple clients so I need to store many credentials and sessions on many same/different sites on browser e.g., google/apple logins, server or domain logins etc for each client.

Is there a browser that enables synchronization with just one email account, allowing the creation of multiple profiles(without email) within it? Whenever I launch the browser from any computer using the same browser account, it would present me with a selection of profiles to choose from. Each profile would retain its own set of bookmarks, frequently visited sites, and other stored data in a particular window like Google Chrome provides.

Or any workaround with a particular browser?

After some research, I found a plugin for Firefox called "Multi-Account Container" by Mozilla that provides similar functionality but the process is quite tedious and opens different profile tabs within the same window which makes it quite confusing.

Comment: This might be worth asking at [softwarerecs.se] but you would need to clearly define your requirements and read their [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: That sounds about right, though the answers may include a workaround with the existing tool or some other technical hack that fulfils the requirement. I hope I have put up my requirement clearly enough. Any edits to the question to improve its quality is always welcome.

Comment: Isn't this what Chrome profiles achieves?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Software Recommendations SE.